Radius of curvature of parametric equation for a helix
The equations i have for the $x, y, z$ coordinates for a helix are as follows
$$x = R\cos(\omega t)$$
$$y = R\sin(\omega t)$$
$$z = vt$$
Where v is the velocity of the particle moving on the path of the helix along the z-axis.
I saw the following formula for general radius of curvature on wikipedia
$$\kappa = \frac{\sqrt{\bigl(z''y' - y''z'\bigr)^2 + \bigl(x''z' - z''x'\bigr)^2 + \bigl(y''x' - x''y'\bigr)^2}}
             {\bigl({x'}^2 + {y'}^2 + {z'}^2\bigr)^{3/2}}$$
Computing this through gives me the following equation
$$\kappa = \frac{R\omega^2}{v^2 + R^2w^2}$$
However the answer to this problem in my textbook is given to to be the reciprocal of this am i wrong somewhere or is the formula on wikipedia wrong?
Any help would be appreciated!

The radius of curvature is $1/\kappa$ according to wikipedia

$\kappa$ is the curvature, not radius of curvature.

On thanks!, sorry for the mistake
